# Swift - JSON decoding returning empty array

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, codable

For my first Swift UIKit app, I am trying to parse some JSON data and use it to populate a UITableView. Ideally, the table view would update with changes to the JSON but this is not entirely necessary right now as the JSON will change very infrequently.

But I'm having some issues parsing the JSON - I seem to be getting an empty array...

The code in my main View Controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//TODO - JSON

struct Visualisation: Codable {
    var id: Int
    let name, info, url_name, tags: String
}

/*
JSON:

[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Two Body Collision",
        "info": "A 2D body collision under the elastic collision assumption",
        "url_name": "https://www.imperialvisualisations.com/visualisations/two-body-collision/two-body-collision/",
        "tags": "Physics, Mechanics"

    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Waves in Dielectrics",
        "info": "The effect of incidence angle & refractive index of dielectric on reflection & transmission",
        "url_name": "https://www.imperialvisualisations.com/visualisations/2d-and-3d-coordinate-systems/2d-polar-coordinates/",
        "tags": "Physics, Maths, Matrices, Linear algebra"
    }
]

This is the structure I am aiming for:

var visualisations: [Visualisation] = [
    .init(id:0, name: "Two Body Collision", info: "A 2D body collision under the elastic collision assumption", url_name: "https://www.imperialvisualisations.com/visualisations/two-body-collision/two-body-collision/", tags: "Physics, Mechanics"),
    .init(id:2, name: "Waves in Dielectrics", info: "The effect of incidence angle & refractive index of dielectric on reflection & transmission", url_name: "https://www.imperialvisualisations.com/visualisations/single-wave-in-3d/boundry-conditions/", tags: "Physics, Electromagnetism, Light, Refractive index, Angle of incidence")
]

 */

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var visualisations = [Visualisation]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ao7in") else { fatalError("JSON URL not found") }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { fatalError("JSON data not loaded") }

            guard let decodedVisualisations = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Visualisation].self, from: data) else { fatalError("Failed to decode JSON")}

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.visualisations = decodedVisualisations
            }

        }.resume()

        print("visualisations")
        print(visualisations)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        title = "Visualisations"

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return visualisations.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //visualisation at row in view
        let visualisation = visualisations[indexPath.row]
        //recast! ??
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        cell.setCell(visualisation: visualisation)

        //set Cell just sets the elements of the table cell in another file

        return cell

    }
}
```

I am not getting any error messages however the decoding seems to be doing nothing to the 'visualisations' array.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: You are *not getting any error messages* because you are ignoring the Decoding error. Add a `do - catch` block, remove the `guard` and the question mark after `try` and `print(error)` in the `catch` clause.

Comment: Have you tried to add explicit table reload somewhere? For example, right after `self.visualisations = decodedVisualisations` line.

Comment: ... and `print(visualisations)` shows an empty array because `dataTask` works asynchronously and returns its data much later.

Answer (score 1):

As per @vadian commented, this works just fine.

```
struct Visualisation: Codable {
    var id: Int
    let name, info, url_name, tags: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var visualisations = [Visualisation]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ao7in") else { fatalError("JSON URL not found") }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { fatalError("JSON data not loaded") }

            do {
                let decodedVisualisations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Visualisation].self, from: data)
                self.visualisations = decodedVisualisations
            } catch let error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, never ever suggest to print `error.localizedDescription` in a `JSONDe/-Encoder` catch block. You'll get a meaningless generic error message. Print always the `error` instance to get a comprehensive error description. By the way `error` is implicitly available in the catch block since Swift 3, `let error` is redundant.